# Host ASP (.NET 6) in a Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, .net-6.0

I am currently hosting an ASP.NET (.NET 5) application in a Windows Service using WebHost and WebHostBuilder.

.NET 6 introduced WebApplication and WebApplicationBuilder. How can I use these to host in a Windows Service?

Comment: The same way you used the `WebHost`/`WebHostBuilder`.

Comment: @GuruStron Here is the .NET source code for hosting in a Windows Service. As you can see is based on IWebHost. Can you show me how to use WebApplication instead of IWebHost?
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4e7d976438b0fc17f435804e801d5d68d193ec33/src/Hosting/WindowsServices/src/WebHostWindowsServiceExtensions.cs

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You would use the `UseWindowsService()` extension method documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-configuration

As is the case in previous versions, you need to install the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` NuGet package.

Implementing this in .NET 6 with `WebApplicationBuilder` requires a workaround:

```cs
var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions() { ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory, Args = args, ApplicationName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName };
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
```

**Updated**:

[Microsoft has changed](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/23387) how services should be created as the fix for this. The `--contentRoot` argument should be used with the exe.

```
sc config MyWebAppServiceTest binPath= "$pwd\WebApplication560.exe --contentRoot $pwd\"
```

```
New-Service -Name {SERVICE NAME} -BinaryPathName "{EXE FILE PATH} --contentRoot {EXE FOLDER PATH}" -Credential "{DOMAIN OR COMPUTER NAME\USER}" -Description "{DESCRIPTION}" -DisplayName "{DISPLAY NAME}" -StartupType Automatic
```

Comment: Thanks @aweyeahdawg But if I am not mistaken, that article shows how to use IHostBuilder whereas I would like to use WebApplicationBuilder.

Comment: I updated my answer with the code you'd need to add

Comment: Looks promising @aweyeahdawg  Going to try it and accept answer if it works.

Comment: Thank you @aweyeahdawg Your answer works but there is a trick to it. Calling UseWindowsService() changes the content root which is not supported using WebApplicationBuilder.Host. I had to do this:

WebApplicationOptions webApplicationOptions = new()
{
    ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory,
    Args = args,
    ApplicationName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

Comment: @Sandy this is what I was looking for. Had everything else, but, could not figure out what the h*ck was going on.

Comment: @Sandy thanks for your comment, I've search all over for how to do this. If anyone is able to edit the accepted answer (I can't) to include this I think it would be helpful to other people.

Comment: @sandy can you post a separate working answer ?

Comment: @Sandy...I think people frown at the "Thank you", but you saved my you-know-where.  Thank you!

Comment: Surprisingly, for me adding `--contentRoot` command line option eliminated any need to mess with `WebApplicationOptions`, but the opposite was not true: I got exception when I was setting the content root through `WebApplicationOptions` without specifying the command line option. Anyway, I hope the developers will straighten this up soon... Cause none of these workarounds looks good.

Comment: .NET 7.0 has swapped builder.Host.UseWindowsService() with builder.Services.AddWindowsService(), which I think semantically looks nicer. It'll be like: builder.Services.AddWindowsService() followed by builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyWindowsHostService>()

Comment: _"As is the case in previous versions, you need to install the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices NuGet package"_. In **.NET Core 3.1** and **.NET 6.0** I was using `IWebHost.RunAsService()` from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices` assembly and this still exists for **.NET 8.0**. I wonder why this package exists?

Answer (score 0):

I had an existing console app that was only running an `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService` implementation targeting .Net 6 and wanted to add a web interface that would be available when the service was running. I think this is what you're doing.

**Steps**

1. Switching the `Sdk` attribute on the root node of the project file
   [image]
2. Reload the project
3. Updated the code in Program.cs

**New Program Class**

```cs
using MyWindowsService.App;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

// Create the builder from the WebApplication but don't call built yet
var appBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add the windows service class as a HostedService to the service collection on the builder
appBuilder.Services.AddHostedService<MyWindowsService>();

// Build the builder to get a web application we can map endpoints to
var app = appBuilder.Build();

// Map an endpoint
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

// Run the web application 
app.Run();
```

**Old Program Class**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MyWindowsService.App
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<MyWindowsService>();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Troy, your answer is actually what I was looking for, thanks! Could you confirm 2 things? A. Is MyWindowsService deriving from BackgroundService and has an ExecuteAsync() method? B. Doesn't the appBuilder need a "appBuilder.Host.UseWindowsService()" for it to work? (Some older tutorials are mentioning this, but it might be just an old requirement... Cheers!

Comment: A. MyWindowsService only implements the interface IHostedService B. No. The Program.cs code in this answer triggered the `Start` and `Stop` functions of the service as expected.

Comment: Interesting! BackgroundService in ver 7.x has default implementations for IHostedService's StartAsync and StopAsync, so a little bit better for me. Then, Microsoft official sample was not working for me, and adding builder.Host.UseWindowsService(); did the magic trick. UseWindowsService() gradually calls an AddWindowsServiceLifetime() internal method, which sounds to be essential... Thanks again! 

Comment: This answer shows how to turn a console service app into a web service app. There is nothing mentioned about an actual "Windows Service".