# .NET 6 UseWindowsService() throws exception

Tags: windows-services, .net-6.0

Here's my "ENTIRE" code in program.cs.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "error");

app.Run();
```

Packages:

- Grpc.AspNetCore(2.47.0)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices (6.0.0)

I deployed this a test server and tried to start the service...and I got this in the Event Log:

> Application: PartReservationGrpc.exe CoreCLR Version: 6.0.622.26707
> .NET Version: 6.0.6 Description: The process was terminated due to an
> unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.NotSupportedException: The
> content root changed from "C:\windows\system32" to
> "D:\CMAP\iceman\partreservation". Changing the host configuration
> using WebApplicationBuilder.Host is not supported. Use
> WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions) instead.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ConfigureHostBuilder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(Action`1 configureDelegate)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.UseContentRoot(IHostBuilder hostBuilder, String contentRoot)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.UseWindowsService(IHostBuilder hostBuilder, Action`1 configure)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.UseWindowsService(IHostBuilder
> hostBuilder)    at Program.$(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\WuJ22\source\Workspaces\C5CG2133PXF\gRPC\PartReservation\PartReservation\PartReservationGrpc\Program.cs:line
> 33

line 33: is exactly where the UseWindowsService() is made.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Can you please add a [mre]?

Comment: @GuruStron...I just posted my entire program.cs (I removed all the other code to isolate the problem)...90+% was out of the box from VS2022...all I did was adding the UseWindowsService call.

Comment: How do you deploy it?

Comment: right now, I am using the "sc" command to install the service on my desktop and point Release folder local on my desktop.  BTW, the executable works fine if I run it through cmd.  Just doesn't like it when I try to run it as a Service

Comment: @GuruStron...I just looked at the doc....UseWindowsService tries to set content root...the way it set the contentroot must not be compatible with 6.0.  Since you got it to work...would u mind, sharing me your package info and/or the code?

Comment: Note that you can always manually switch back to the generic hosting model (the one with `Startup` and so on). One way is to create .NET 5 solution and  change target framework to .net6.0. Or just manually copy the setup code (`Program.cs` and `Startup`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571849/host-asp-net-6-in-a-windows-service):

The trick is calling the **CreateBuilder()** with the **WebApplicationOptions** to set the **ContentRootPath**.