# Multiple IHostBuilders hosted in a single Windows service: "Stopped without starting"

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-services

I am attempting to host two web apps in a single Windows service.  I create them both using "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder".  I run them using

```
await Task.WhenAny(
  host1.Build().RunAsync(),
  host2.Build().RunAsync()
);
```

When I run this as a console app (i.e. "host1.UseConsoleLifetime();") it works like a charm.  When I try this inside a Windows service (i.e. "host1.UseWindowsService();"), one of the two will always fault immediately with an exception saying "Stopped without starting" coming from "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting".

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this answer helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571849/host-asp-net-6-in-a-windows-service

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and some exceptions with stack trace and logs?